# How to fix "swapping stylesheet function" in js

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to code a stylesheet swapper in javascript but it's not working. the general idea is that i trigger the function when i click the button, but i want to be able to swap back to the first css in when i click it again. Could you find me the reason it's not working? 
Thanks!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
            document.getElementById('swap').setAttribute('href', sheet);
        }
        function initate() {
        var cont=0;
    var style1 = document.getElementById("stylesheet1");

        if(cont==0){
    style1 = swapStyleSheet("styleH_V2.css");
        cont=cont+1;}
        else{
        style1 = swapStyleSheet("styleH.css");
        cont=cont-1;
        }
}
        </script>
```

```html
<button id="stylesheet1" onclick="initate();"> Alternative Style Sheet </button>
```

the first time i click the button it actually triggers the function and works but if i click again im not able to switch back to the original css because the button does not work.

Answer (score 1):

**A contribution by ing. W.K.K. Hofman.**

### Introduction

To start with, I think you're not looking for a possibility to swap between stylesheets, but to toggle between them.

There are two common methods of changing stylesheets in front-end development, toggeling (switching between two specific stylesheets, or swapping (replacing a stylesheet with one of infinitely different variants of stylesheets).

In either case, the index.html file will still have the usual reference to a default stylesheet. The magic happens when you add an identifier to the reference to a default stylesheet. I added an id=pagestyle in my example.

This identifier allows you to change the value of the href attribute in the reference to a default stylesheet with an id=pagestyle, by targeting it in a JavaScript.

The reference to the stylesheet should look like this:

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet_default.css"/>
```

### Method 2; Change stylesheets with the stylesheet_swapper.js file

The following JavaScript file contains a function called 'swap_stylesheet' with a container called 'target_stylesheet'. This container called 'target_stylesheet' stores the value (location and filename of the stylesheet) of the stylesheet to be used during a session, after clicking on a list item, href attribute, button etc.

The line of code "document.getElementById("pagestyle").setAttribute("href", target_stylesheet);", targets an element in the index.html file with an identifier id="pagestyle", and sets the href attribute within that element, with the value stored in the target_stylesheet container, when an element in the index.html file with an onclick attribute pointing to the function called "swap_stylesheet", is clicked.

This element with an onclick attribute, which is triggered when you click on it, stores a specified value (location and filename of the stylesheet) in the container called "target_stylesheet".

My swap_stylesheet.js file looks like this:

```
// swap_stylesheet.js

/*
A JavaScript that allows you, to let the reader change the pagestyle. You can use it to let them switch between different colour modes, or switch between dark/light mode, by different stylesheets for every mode.
*/

function swap_stylesheet(target_stylesheet) { 
            
    document.getElementById("pagestyle").setAttribute("href", target_stylesheet);

}

/*
With this JavaScript, you can provide HTML elements with a swap-stylesheet functionality by a onclick attribute. The possibilities are endless, but here are following two of them.

Example 1 - Changing stylesheet by listitems:

<li onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_default.css')"> Default </li>
<li onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_grayscale.css')"> Grayscale </li>
<li onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_grayscale.css')"> Without Style </li>

Example 2 - Changing stylesheet by a href attribute:

<a onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_default.css')"> Default </a>
<a onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_grayscale.css')"> Grayscale </a>
<a onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_none.css')"> Without Style </a>
*/
```

My index.html file is as follows:

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet_default.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="swap_stylesheet.js"> </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container wrapper">

            <header id="top">

                <h1>Welkome to My Homepage</h1>
                <p>Use the menu to select different stylesheets</p>

            </header>

            <div class="wrapper">

                <div id="menubar">

                    <ul id="menulist">

                        <li class="menuitem" onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_default.css')"> Default </li>
                        <li class="menuitem" onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_grayscale.css')"> Grayscale </li>
                        <li class="menuitem" onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_none.css')"> Without Style </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div id="main">

                    <h1>Same Page Defferent Stylesheets</h1>
                    <p>
                     This is a demonstration of how different stylesheets can change the layout of your HTML page. You can change the layout of this page by selecting different stylesheets in the menu, or by selecting one of the following links:

                     <br>
                     
                     <a onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_default.css')"> Default </a>,
                     <a onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_grayscale.css')"> Grayscale </a>.
                    </p>

                    <h2>No Styles</h2>
                    <p>
                     This page uses DIV elements to group different sections of the HTML page. Click here to see how the page looks like with no stylesheet:
                     
                     <br>

                     <a onclick="swap_stylesheet('stylesheet_none.css')"> Without Style </a>.
                    </p> 
           
                </div>

                <aside id="sidebar">

                    <h3>Side-Bar</h3>
                    <p>
                    Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, set diamnonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                    </p>

                </aside>

            </div>

            <footer id="bottom">
                
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi."

            </footer>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

My stylesheet_defaulte.css file is as follows:

```
/* stylesheet_defaulte.css | variables */

:root { --color_1: rgba(255,255,255,1); 
        --color_2: rgba(246,218,215,1); 
        --color_3: rgba(209,072,000,1); }


/* stylesheet_defaulte.css */

body                   { font-family     : Arial                   ; 
                         background-color: var(--color_3)          ; 
                         line-height     : 20px                    ; }

.container             { min-width       : 300px                   ; }

.wrapper               { position        : relative                ; 
                         overflow        : auto                    ; }

#top                   { color           : var(--color_1)          ; 
                         padding         : 15px                    ; 
                         font-size       : 30px                    ;
                         line-height     : 26px                    ; }

#top h1                { margin          : 0                       ;
                         line-height     : 50px                    ; }

#menubar               { width           : 190px                   ;
                         float           : right                   ; }

#main                  { padding         : 10px                    ;
                         background-color: var(--color_1)          ;
                         font            : 80% Verdana             ; }

#main h1, #main h2     { color           : var(--color_3)          ; }

#sidebar               { background-color: var(--color_2)          ;
                         color           : var(--color_3)          ;
                         padding         : 10px                    ; }

#bottom                { text-align      : center                  ;
                         padding         : 10px                    ;
                         font-size       : 70%                     ;
                         color           : var(--color_1)          ; }

#menulist              { padding         : 0                       ;
                         font            : 16px verdana            ; }

.menuitem              { width           : 155px                   ;
                         background-color: var(--color_3)          ;
                         border          : 1px solid var(--color_3);
                         border-radius   : 40px                    ;
                         color           : var(--color_1)          ;
                         list-style-type : none                    ;
                         margin          : 10px                    ;
                         padding         : 5px                     ;
                         text-align      : center                  ;
                         cursor          : pointer                 ; }

.menuitem:nth-child(2) { background-color: var(--color_1)          ;
                         color           : var(--color_3)          ;
                         font-weight     : bold                    ; }

.menuitem:hover        { background-color: var(--color_1)          ;
                         color           : var(--color_3)          ; }

a                      { color           : var(--color_3)          ;
                         text-decoration : none                    ; }

a:hover                { text-decoration : underline               ; }
```

My stylesheet_grayscale.css file is as follows:

```
/* stylesheet_greyscale.css | variables */

:root { --color_1: rgba(255,255,255,1); 
        --color_2: rgba(050,050,050,1); 
        --color_3: rgba(000,000,000,1); }


/* stylesheet_greyscale.css */

body                   { font-family     : Arial                   ; 
                         background-color: var(--color_3)          ; 
                         line-height     : 20px                    ; }

.container             { min-width       : 300px                   ; }

.wrapper               { position        : relative                ; 
                         overflow        : auto                    ; }

#top                   { color           : var(--color_1)          ; 
                         padding         : 15px                    ; 
                         font-size       : 30px                    ;
                         line-height     : 26px                    ; }

#top h1                { margin          : 0                       ;
                         line-height     : 50px                    ; }

#menubar               { width           : 190px                   ;
                         float           : right                   ; }

#main                  { padding         : 10px                    ;
                         background-color: var(--color_1)          ;
                         font            : 80% Verdana             ; }

#main h1, #main h2     { color           : var(--color_3)          ; }

#sidebar               { background-color: var(--color_2)          ;
                         color           : var(--color_3)          ;
                         padding         : 10px                    ; }

#bottom                { text-align      : center                  ;
                         padding         : 10px                    ;
                         font-size       : 70%                     ;
                         color           : var(--color_1)          ; }

#menulist              { padding         : 0                       ;
                         font            : 16px verdana            ; }

.menuitem              { width           : 155px                   ;
                         background-color: var(--color_3)          ;
                         border          : 1px solid var(--color_3);
                         border-radius   : 40px                    ;
                         color           : var(--color_1)          ;
                         list-style-type : none                    ;
                         margin          : 10px                    ;
                         padding         : 5px                     ;
                         text-align      : center                  ;
                         cursor          : pointer                 ; }

.menuitem:nth-child(2) { background-color: var(--color_1)          ;
                         color           : var(--color_3)          ;
                         font-weight     : bold                    ; }

.menuitem:hover        { background-color: var(--color_1)          ;
                         color           : var(--color_3)          ; }

a                      { color           : var(--color_3)          ;
                         text-decoration : none                    ; }

a:hover                { text-decoration : underline               ; }
```

My stylesheet_none.css file is as follows:

```
/* stylesheet_none.css */
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `initate` function is always declaring `cont` to be zero at each execution, therefore it will always go into `if(cont==0)`, you might want to declare the `cont`variable outside of the function scope:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cont = 0;
....
function initate() { ... }
</script>
```

On a side note, you should use === to compare numbers instead of == to avoid internal casting of values. Also see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).